# Flutter ListView getting automatically updated at wrong index or element

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I am trying to make a list view that shows an addition to a certain number. Here in the image, I am trying to generate an addition table for 16 steps in a ListView. It appears fine when it gets loaded but after scrolling the top and the bottom element gets updated automatically. This problem is only evident when the value of the variable *tableSize* that basically controls the number of items in the ListView exceeds 15. How can this problem be solved??

[image: top and bottom element of the ListView gets updated automatically]

// tableSize = 16 && tCount = 10

Here is the code

```
return ListView.builder(
  key: UniqueKey(),
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
  itemCount: DataFile.tableSize,
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    tCount = tCount + 1;

    String title;

    print(" Tcount = ${tCount}");

    if (sign == DataFile.divisionSign) {
      double ans = tableNo / tCount;
      title = tableNo.toString() +
          space +
          sign +
          space +
          tCount.toString() +
          space +
          equal +
          space +
          f.format(ans);
    } else {
      int ans;
      if (sign == DataFile.additionSign) {
        ans = tableNo + tCount;
      } else if (sign == DataFile.subtractionSign) {
        ans = tableNo - tCount;
      } else {
        ans = tableNo * tCount;
      }

      title = tableNo.toString() +
          space +
          space +
          sign +
          space +
          space +
          tCount.toString() +
          space +
          space +
          equal +
          space +
          space +
          int.parse(ans.toString()).toString();
      print(title);
    }

    return InkWell(
      child: Container(
        height: cellHeight,
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            vertical: ConstantData.getScreenPercentSize(context, 2.3)),
        child: Center(
          child: ConstantWidget.getTextWidget(
              title,
              ConstantData.textColors!,
              ConstantData.getPercentSize(cellHeight, 98),
              FontWeight.w500,
              TextAlign.center),
        ),
      ),
      onTap: () {},
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: Use this inside itemBuilder:  tCount = index + 1; instead of  tCount = tCount + 1;

Comment: yes, it works perfectly fine!                                                                                                          thanks for this suggestion, I was really struggling with this one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change required in the **tCount** which is mutable data in the state variable.

Use this code:

```
return ListView.builder(
  key: UniqueKey(),
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
  itemCount: DataFile.tableSize,
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {

tCount = index + 1; //change here 

String title;

print(" Tcount = ${tCount}");

if (sign == DataFile.divisionSign) {
  double ans = tableNo / tCount;
  title = tableNo.toString() +
      space +
      sign +
      space +
      tCount.toString() +
      space +
      equal +
      space +
      f.format(ans);
} else {
  int ans;
  if (sign == DataFile.additionSign) {
    ans = tableNo + tCount;
  } else if (sign == DataFile.subtractionSign) {
    ans = tableNo - tCount;
  } else {
    ans = tableNo * tCount;
  }

  title = tableNo.toString() +
      space +
      space +
      sign +
      space +
      space +
      tCount.toString() +
      space +
      space +
      equal +
      space +
      space +
      int.parse(ans.toString()).toString();
  print(title);
}

return InkWell(
  child: Container(
    height: cellHeight,
    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: ConstantData.getScreenPercentSize(context, 2.3)),
    child: Center(
      child: ConstantWidget.getTextWidget(
          title,
          ConstantData.textColors!,
          ConstantData.getPercentSize(cellHeight, 98),
          FontWeight.w500,
          TextAlign.center),
    ),
  ),
  onTap: () {},
);
},
);
```